# PL/SQL retrieve multiple rows using SELECT INTO in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dml, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger, that fires when a new row is being inserted into a table. The trigger should check if that table have any rows, that have a value in a column that equals the value from the same column in the inserting row. Then I need to update rows in the original table that have the same ID as the selected ones. Now I need to  make a request to retrieve the data (all the columns), and that's when I get in troubles.

The problem is that I need to declare a variable, that will be used to store result of that request. That variable should have the same type as the table I retrieve data from does, but when I declare it like that (REC_ROAD_INT is my table):

`DECLARE REQUEST_RESULT REC_ROAD_INT%TYPE;`

I get

`%TYPE must be applied to a variable, column, field or attribute, not to "REC_ROAD_INT"`

I actually can retrieve data I need, but only in those cases when the table have only 1 row that meets a requirement. Here's a sample:

```
create or replace TRIGGER INSERT_ROAD_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON REC_ROAD_INT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  ROAD_ID NUMBER;
  ROAD_NAME VARCHAR2(20);
  ROAD_START_KM NUMBER;
  ROAD_END_KM NUMBER;
BEGIN 
    SELECT ID, NAME, START_KM, END_KM INTO ROAD_ID, ROAD_NAME, ROAD_START_KM, ROAD_END_KM
    FROM REC_ROAD_INT
    WHERE (:NEW.START_KM BETWEEN START_KM AND END_KM) OR 
      (:NEW.END_KM BETWEEN START_KM AND END_KM);
    IF INSERTING 
    THEN 
      DBMS_Output.Put_Line('INSERTING');
      DBMS_Output.Put_Line('Inserting road: ' || :NEW.ID || ' ' || :New.NAME || ' ' || :New.START_KM || ' ' || :New.END_KM);
      DBMS_Output.Put_Line('Crossing road: ' || 'ID = ' || ROAD_ID || ', NAME = ' || ROAD_NAME || 
              ', START_KM = ' || ROAD_START_KM || ', END_KM = ' || ROAD_END_KM);
    END IF;
END;
```

How can I get all the rows? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a `cursor`

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a compound trigger http://viralpatel.net/blogs/compound-triggers-in-oracle-11g-tutorial-example/

Comment: @Akio Hamasaki, that's a good idea, I will try that

Comment: A row-level trigger on `REC_ROAD_INT` cannot in general query `REC_ROAD_INT` without throwing a mutating table exception.  A compound trigger or a series of row- and statement-level triggers (depending on the Oracle version) and potentially a package with a collection can be used but that's a bit complex.  This looks like the sort of thing that ought to be validated by the procedure that does the insert rather than through a trigger.

Comment: That is why you always must use a cursor in stead of a select into statement.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to declare a variable of table type. Your problem is that that variable is not %TYPE but %ROWTYPE.

```
DECLARE
  emp_rec scott.emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 .....
END;
/
```

Your second requirement is pretty confusing. Remove where condition to get all rows. You need to be more specific and clear.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove `WHERE` condition, cause I want only those rows that meet that condition, the problem is that there could be multiple rows

Comment: Then what is the problem? Open explicit cursor and loop and get all that you need. Open any Oracle book or web and read the differences between Implicit and Explicit cursors.

Comment: I kinda forgot to mention it in my question, but I also need to update those rows that meet the requirement in my table, but only if I'm actually inserting something (that's why I have `IF INSERTING ` in my code. The problem is that you can't use `SELECT` clause inside of `IF` statement, so I need to do it outside and store results somewhere.